# How do I query for non-scalar JSON values in PL/SQL

Tags: json, oracle, scalar

I have the following JSON input:

```
[{a:1}, {a:2}]
```

I want the following tabular output (a single varchar2 column / two rows):

```
{a:1}
{a:2}
```

I tried:

```
select * from json_table(
   '[{a:1}, {a:2}]',
   '$[*]'
   error on error
   columns xxx varchar2 path '$'
);
```

I get:

```
ORA-40456: JSON_VALUE evaluated to non-scalar value
```

How do I query those non-scalar JSON values such as '{a:1}' in their entirety in PL/SQL? I understand that JSON_QUERY is the non-scalar counterpart to JSON_VALUE, but I'm not using JSON_VALUE explicitly, so I don't know where I would plug in JSON_QUERY in this query.

(In real life, those JSON values in the initial array will be complex structures, so I don't want to parse them all the way down to their scalar components and then piece them together again).

I use Oracle 18.1

Comment: Interesting question. When we build complex JSON from base tables (for example, by joining the SCOTT.EMP and SCOTT.DEPT tables), we can follow the way the JSON is built at every step - lowest-level objects, assembled into arrays of objects, incorporated into higher-level objects, assembled again in higher-level arrays, etc. What you are asking is the opposite process: Starting with a complex JSON (even as simple as an array of lowest-level objects), can we decompose it **step by step**? I don't know the answer, but I'll look into it, since it's a really good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work ok if you use a [json_query](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56973) column definition.

```
select * from json_table(
   '[{a:1}, {a:2}]',
   '$[*]'
   error on error
   columns xxx varchar2 FORMAT JSON path '$'
);
```

Comment: This will wrap the "keys" within double-quotes, but that should be OK for the OP's purposes.

Comment: @mathguy That is because the OP's JSON input does not strictly match the [JSON specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) as their input should be `[{"a":1, {"a":2}]`. However, JSON parsers tend to be permissive and will parse object keys without the surrounding quotes so it will "work".

Comment: @MT0 - yes, exactly. Oracle documentation explicitly states that it allows lax syntax (so the OP's input is actually valid from Oracle's point of view). Understandably, when Oracle converts to JSON, it follows strict syntax. And, as JSON strings, the two are equivalent (from lax syntax point of view), so there is no reason the OP should insist that the output follow lax syntax.

Comment: @kfinity Thanks, that's it. So it's a matter of reading the docs and following through those syntax diagrams Oracle kindly provides. Thanks for doing it for me and for providing the link. For some reason nothing like that popped up in my searches.

Comment: @mathguy yes, the generated strict syntax is of course OK for me. Thanks for your participation!